# Can't generate scaffolding with Yeoman

Tags: node.js, angularjs, npm, yeoman, bower

I'm following this [tutorial](http://www.sitepoint.com/kickstart-your-angularjs-development-with-yeoman-grunt-and-bower/) to scaffold an application with generators (webapp and angular). I can install all dependencies and generators but when I run the commands `yo webapp` or `yo angular` I don't get any output feedback and when I run `ls` nothing was generated. When I diplay the npm installed packages with `npm -g list` I can see `yo`, `bower` and `grunt` packages are installed.

I'm using Ubuntu 13.04 64 bits and npm, yo, bower and grunt are installed in the `usr/lib/node_module` directory. I've checked some posts and questions about possible installation/directory problems but I can really get what's the real problem. Did I miss something during the instalation?

**UPDATE**
I tried installing all in Windows 7 and it works. So I think there are installation problems on Ubuntu, but I can't still figure out how to fix that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You installed `node`, the Amateur Packet Radio Node program, instead of `nodejs`.

Run `apt-get remove node && apt-get install nodejs` and everything will be fine.